# Xcopy sharing violation, how to still copy without skipping

Tags: makefile, cmake, robocopy, xcopy, file-copying

I’m copying files from one directory to another with Windows xcopy command in cmake. Sometimes I run into situations where one file is already being used by another program, which results in a sharing violation error. Therefore, the file does not get copied and my compilation fails.

How do I get around this without skipping over files that are already being used. I don’t have the option to close any open files.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to kill the process or program which uses the file that you are copying via task manager and try again.

/c will be used to skip the file and continue copying but in your case, you dont want to skip the files that are already being used.